# How do I access a function written in a certain class inside of a friend function of said class?

Tags: c++

I am in the middle of a homework assignment, where we are tasked to write operator overloading functions, and are given a header file named xArray.h, shown here:

```
#ifndef XARRAY_H_
#define XARRAY_H_

#include <stddef.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class xArray{
  size_t len;
  size_t arraySize; 

  //data of int array
  int* data;
public:
  // Constructors
  xArray();
  xArray(const xArray& a);   
  xArray(const int x);//create an array with x elements

  //copy constructor to get n integer from an C style array, 
  //n is assumed to be < the length of of that array
  xArray(const int * a, size_t n); 

  // Destructor
  ~xArray();

  // Assignment and modification operators
  xArray& operator=(const xArray& right); 

  //make the array hold only one integer
  xArray& operator=(const int c); 

  //merge two arrays, append all elements from right to the end of this
  xArray& operator+=(const xArray& right); 

  //add c to the end of this array
  xArray& operator+=(const int c); 

  // Put an int at the end of data, can be used by operators "+=", ">>" 
  size_t PushBack(const int c);

  // Put an int at the beginning of the data.
  size_t PushFront(const int c);

  // set len to 0, i.e. the array is cleared
  void Clear(void);             

  // index operator, if idx over bound, print message and quit
  int operator[](size_t idx) const;
  //get the length of the xArray& 
  size_t Length() const { return len; } 

  //overloaded << operator, print all elements of the array. A line can at most
  //hold 20 elements
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const xArray& a);

  //>> operator, get one int and put it at the end of the array
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, xArray& a);

};

#endif
```

I am trying to call the PushBack() function inside of the friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, xArray& a) function that I have written inside of the .cpp file, like this:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, xArray& a)
{
  a.*PushBack(in);
}
```

but I am being given an error saying:

```
error: ‘PushBack’ was not declared in this scope
```

I have tried everything that Google has been able to give me so far, but  nothing has worked.

Comment: Although the correct syntax is just "a.PushBack(in)", that won't work either, because the PushBack() method takes an `int` as a parameter, and not a `std::istream`. Please de-obfuscate your question.

Comment: Do you know of any way to take in the std::istream even though the parameter asks for an int? We are not allowed to change the .h file, and thus can't change the parameters.

Comment: You could extract an `int` first, then put that in the array.

Comment: I just figured out how to do that properly from an istream variable. I'm an idiot. Thank you both so very much.